# Enrolling for Microsoft SQL Server related Newsletters from Microsoft

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know the process about how to automatically receive information about updates related to SQL Server from Microsoft. I am referring to kind of newsletter kind of alerts..

Updates like :

1. Latest Service pack releases
2. SQL Server Version releases
3. SQL Server enhancements etc...

Can anyone let me know if you already having this ways in place. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this feed for notifications of SQL Server updates https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/